# Android Studio: GridLayout doens´t work in v.3.5

Tags: java, android, grid

[The problem:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10YBc.png) Hello everybody,

I have the problem that I want to use a GridLayout, but here in Android Studio 3.5 it doesn't work like in 3.0.1. Every time I want to add a GridLayout, I have to add it first. I do, but nothing happens. 
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIj3N.png)
There are no attributes displayed in the design and after clicking it again I should add it again - I really have no idea. With 3.0.1 you could simply drag it in and directly edit the rows and columns.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUxKd.png) the build.gradle

Comment: Check if this dependency is added in `build.gradle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app supports Androidx but you are using Gridlayout library for v7 which is only supported upto api 28. Replace your Gridlayout library with latest Androidx Gridlayout library

```
androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout
```

Comment: yes it will work because androidx also include all previous support libraries with new updated libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following dependency in the build.gradle file for your app or module:

```
dependencies {
implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0-rc01'
}
```

It worked for me.